# In php image upload process.. using move_uploaded_file method in php... the selected image is not move to the new floder

Tags: php, file-upload

In php image upload the temp file is to move to the user floder but it is not moving to the new floder.

html code

```
<form method="POST" action="db.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myimage">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

php code

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password11';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('loginn');
$upload_image=$_FILES['myimage'] ['tmp_name'];
echo  $upload_image;
$folder="images/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[' myimage '][' tmp_name '],'$folder'.$_FILES[' myimage '][' name ']);
$insert_path="INSERT INTO demo(path,image)   VALUES('$folder','$upload_image')";
$var=mysql_query($insert_path);
 ?>
```

Comment: you have spaces in `$_FILES[' myimage '][' tmp_name ']` maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" action="db.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myimage">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload">
 </form>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"];
$name = "images/".$_FILES['myimage']['name'];
$filename=$_FILES['myimage']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$name))
{
    $insert_path="INSERT INTO image_table (path,name) VALUES('images/','$filename')";
    $var=mysql_query($insert_path);
    if(!$var)
    {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Change the code like this... Dont leave the spaces between array names.

```
  [' myimage '][' tmp_name ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space from `[' myimage '][' tmp_name '] and [' myimage '][' name ']`

Answer (score 0):

You used `'$folder'` (with quotes), but you should use `$folder` (without quotation marks). And also need to remove space ['myimage'] ['tmp_name'] and ['myimage'] ['name'].

You can use this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'],$folder.$_FILES['myimage']['name']);
```

I hope this helps!